# How to detect if object collide with each other if all I have is a list of their positions and their size?

Tags: c#

I have a lot of circles and I store their position in a list.
All circles have the same radius.

How can I detect if any circle collides with another circle?
What would be the fastest way?

Comment: C# is a language of types - what is the C# type of the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collision detection of huge number of circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544431/collision-detection-of-huge-number-of-circles)

Answer (score 1):

Given the Pythagorean Theorem, `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`, if you take `dx = circle[0].x - circle[1].x`, `dy = circle[0].y - circle[1].y`, then you can get the hypotenuse which is the straight-line distance between centers by `hypotenuse = Mathf.Sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2);`.

However, you don't actually need the distance/hypotenuse, you just need to know if that value is less than 2*r, or two radii, because if the distance between the two circles is less than that then you know they're colliding.

This means that you don't need to take the square root, you can just leave it squared and compare it to the collision distance squared, or `(2*r)^2`. That is, you are colliding when:

```
(dx^2 + dy^2) <= (2*r)^2
```

In code, it looks like:

```
public class Circle
{
    public float R { get; private set; }
    public float X { get; private set; }
    public float Y { get; private set; }
}
public static bool IsColliding(Circle c0, Circle c1)
{
    var collisionDistance = (c0.R + c1.R)*(c0.R + c1.R);
    var dx = c0.X - c1.X;
    var dy = c0.Y - c1.Y;
    return dx*dx + dy*dy <= collisionDistance;
}
```

If the radii are all the same then you can cache `collisionDistance` and not need to recalculate it on each step.

*NOTE*: My solution here assumes the radii aren't the same; the "2*r" term is replaced by `c0.R + c1.R`. If they're the same then it reduces to `c0.R + c0.R` or `2*c0.R`.

:EDIT: To check collisions, if you have 4 circles, you'd need to check 1 against 2, 3, and 4. Then, because you already checked 1 against 2 you can skip 2 against 1. You just need to check 2 against 3 and 4, then just 3 against 4.

That is, if you have a `List<Circle> circles`, you would get:

```
var nCircles = circles.Count;
for(int i=0; i<nCircles-1; i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1; j<nCircles; j++)
    {
        if(IsColliding(circles[i], circles[j]))
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

This would check 0 against 1,2,3; then 1 against 2,3; then 2 against 3.

Comment: You left out processing the list to find any collisions... Also, with a large list, it may pay to filter with a simpler comparison first...

Comment: @NetMage - Added the list check. And yes, there are still lots of optimizations that could happen, but I don't have anything more than the two lines OP wrote to go on. I'm trying to give an answer that is a bit more generic than OP asked for so it's useful to more people than just OP.

Comment: Well, some simple examples are useful depending on what "a lot of circles" means - for example, `dx * dx` is 100 times faster than `Math.Pow(dx, 2)`

Comment: That looks like a good answer. But I think that it might be really slow (I have 516x516 circles). Also, @NetMage could you explain why Math.Pow is slower there?

Comment: @Theos The C# compiler has no optimizations for simple integer calls to `Math.Pow` so it runs a full general power function (likely log and exp) which is very, very slow compared to a multiplication.

Comment: @Theos - What do you mean when you say you have "516x516 circles?" Do you mean you have 266,256 circles or do you mean you have 516 and you want to check all of them against each other?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a lot of circles (e.g. at least 10,000) and you want to find all circle collisions, you can check each circle against all remaining circles, starting with the first. You can optimize the check by using the bounding box around each circle to filter in only nearby circles, and then test against a diamond inside to filter in close circles and finally test against the full circle to filter out corner circles. Since we know the radius is the same in all cases, we are filtering the centers against a circle of 2*r.

Testing only the circles inside the bounding box is about a 10% speedup, filtering in the circles inside the diamond is about another 1% speedup, and testing in the order given is fastest for collisions of 0.15% to 62% of the total list, but if your list is much smaller, extra tests may cost more time than just the simple test against the bounding circle.

Also if you only care for the first collision for each circle, you can add a `break` statement after the `Add` in the `if` to stop testing once a collision is found.

```
var r = 3.0;

var ans = new List<(int, int)>();
var r2 = 2 * r;
var r_sq = r2 * r2;

for (int j1 = 0; j1 < circles.Count - 1; ++j1) {
    var c1 = circles[j1];
    for (int j2 = j1 + 1; j2 < circles.Count; ++j2) {
        var c2 = circles[j2];
        var dx = Math.Abs(c1.x - c2.x);
        var dy = Math.Abs(c1.y - c2.y);
        if (dx <= r2 && dy <= r2 && ((dx + dy <= r2) || (dx * dx + dy * dy <= r_sq))) {
            ans.Add((j1, j2));
        }
    }
}
```

If this isn't sufficient, and you can store your circles in a different structure, it is probably time to look at something like [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it out tomorrow and come back with the results. 
I have 516x516 circles so thats a lot.

Comment: @Theos on my PC, 516 * 516 takes 49 seconds when there is a very small probability (0.05%) of collision and you find all collisions. Do you have any idea of the probability distribution of collisions? If you need it to be faster, you need to look into better data structures as mentioned, or can you use parallelism?

Comment: 49s is waaay too slow. I move all the circles 60 times per second. Will using better data structure be enough, cuz I have like 15ms to simulate all the collisions.

Comment: @Theos Even using parallel processing, I only get it down to 13 seconds. To use a better data structure, you will need to permanently keep the circles in the right structure, so if they are moving that may be a problem.